# How to set up graphql-upload with koa-graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, koa, koa-router

Currently using koa-graphql to set up a graphql server with koa router, attempting to connect graphql-upload to it so I can upload files, however I'm getting an empty object when sending a file through a mutation

server.js

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import Koa from 'koa';
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser';
import Router from 'koa-router';
import graphqlHTTP from 'koa-graphql';
import schema from './../graphql/schema';
import rootValue from './../graphql/resolvers/index';

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;

const server = new Koa();
const router = new Router();
server.use(bodyParser({jsonLimit: '50mb'})); 
router.all('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({schema, rootValue}));
server.use(router.allowedMethods());
server.use(router.routes());
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on PORT ${port}`));
```

schema.js

```
import {buildSchema} from 'graphql';

export default buildSchema(`
  scalar Upload

  type Obj {
    _id: ID!
    image: String!
    title: String!
  }

  type RootQuery {
    objs: [Obj]!
  }

  type RootMutation {
    createObj(obj: ObjInput!): String!
  }

  input ObjInput {
    title: String!
    image: Upload!
  }

  schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
  }
`);
```

resolvers

```
import rootQuery from './query';
import rootMutation from './mutations';
import {GraphQLUpload} from 'graphql-upload';

export default {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  ...rootQuery,
  ...rootMutation
};
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-graphql

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`graphql-upload` setup instructions](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#setup), you need to implement the [`graphqlUploadKoa`](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#function-graphqluploadkoa) middleware from [`graphql-upload`](https://npm.im/graphql-upload).

Example:

```js
import { graphqlUploadKoa } from 'graphql-upload';
```

```js
// Ideally set this up for POST requests on the `/graphql` route, before GraphQL server middleware runs.
koaApp.use(graphqlUploadKoa({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the guide found in the graphql-upload npm documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload .

```
import  { GraphQLUpload , graphqlUploadKoa } from 'graphql-upload'

new Koa().use(graphqlUploadKoa({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }))
```

In your schema, add this uptop

```js
typeDefs: /* GraphQL */ `
    scalar Upload
  `,
```

In your resolver

```js
  resolvers: {
    Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  },
```